# AngularJS - state parameters don't persist to controller using ui-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What seems to be an issue for me is how to use `$state.go(state, params)` and have `params` persist through to the state's controller, regardless of a component.  The plunkr I've setup that demonstrates this is linked here: https://plnkr.co/edit/u5VaMZIBtVoBGbAZaQe0?p=preview

Basically what I'm doing is setting up 2 states, one links to the other.  I'm using `$state.go` to go one of those states with passed parameters.  It doesn't appear those parameters are passed though and I'm wondering why this is.

I'm using AngularJS version 1.6.6 and ui.router version 0.4.2 if that makes a difference or not.

```
var app = angular.module("yay", ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  var states = [
    {
      name: 'paramsDontWork',
      url: '/doesntwork',
      template: '<div>hi{{variable}}</div><a style="color:blue;" ng-click="goto()">goto</a>',
      controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $scope.variable = 'hi';
        $scope.goto = function() {
          $state.go('newplace', { should: "should"});
        };
      }],
    },
    {
      name: 'newplace',
      url: '/newplace',
      template: 'new place {{should}} have params<br><a ui-sref="paramsDontWork">hi</a>',
      controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
        console.log($stateParams);
        $scope.should = $stateParams.should;
      }]
    }
  ];

  states.forEach(function(state) {
    $stateProvider.state(state);
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/doesntwork');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes must explicitly specify any parameters that can be overwritten (e.g. transition from another route) as part of their state configuration.

[Relevant guidance from the UI-Router documentation:](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.4.2/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go_parameters)

> Any parameters that are not specified will be inherited from currently defined parameters. Only parameters specified in the state definition can be overridden, **new parameters will be ignored.**

(Emphasis mine.)

In your example, `/newplace` doesn't specify a `params` property to provide the additional non-URL parameter.

All you need to do to ensure value of `should` from `/doesntwork` gets passed is to explicitly declare it as part of `/newplace` as a parameter with some default value:

```
{
    name: 'newplace',
    ...
    params: { should: null },
}
```

[Plunker fork to demonstrate the above.](https://plnkr.co/edit/JcWwZxy1Ixlxs2aWxJMw?p=preview)

Comment: *sigh* of course it's something simple like that.  Thanks much.  Application is working a charm now.